# filterChain.doFilter is not moving to next filter

Tags: servlets, jax-rs, servlet-filters

Here is my piece of code for a filter

```java
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
    
    String path = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getRequestURI();
    LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Current request path :: {0}", path);
    if (ignorePath(path)) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "continuing to next filter");
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
    LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Should not come here");

}
```

logging is done just for debugging purposes.
I am getting below logs on execution.

**2020-07-18T12:02:30.805301+00:00 app[web.1]: Jul 18, 2020 12:02:30 PM security.filter.SecurityFilter doFilter**

**2020-07-18T12:02:30.805302+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: continuing to next filter**

**2020-07-18T12:02:30.889518+00:00 app[web.1]: Jul 18, 2020 12:02:30 PM security.filter.SecurityFilter doFilter**

**2020-07-18T12:02:30.889520+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: Should not come here**

What is really going wrong here? The log **Should not come here**, shouldn't be printed(That is what I expect).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `doFilter()` is called each time when a request/response is passed through the chain. The `FilterChain.doFilter()` method invokes the next filter in the chain and calls resource at the end of the chain if the filter is the last filter in the chain.

This is just a normal method and after it's execution the control will come to the next line. That's the reason you're getting the log after the `if` condition.

If you want to ignore the execution of the next filter for certain URIs, I recommend you use the `else` block.

```java
if (ignorePath(path)) {
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
    LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Called doFilter for this URI");
} else {
    LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "doFilter is not called for this URI");
}
```